# Will adding multiple indexes slow down frequently inserting rows to the end of a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've heard the benefits of indexes and I've heard the cons as well. One of which is that INSERT becomes slower. If I have a table that I am frequently appending a single row to the end of, is that a good reason not to not use indexes?

Comment: When you **ONLY** consider the insert operations - then yes, any additional index will cause additional overhead and thus slow down your inserts. But the question is: without any indexes - would your search / `SELECT` still be fast enough? What's more important to your overall system performance - just fast `INSERT`s - or also fast `SELECT`s ?

Comment: Also consider how often you are writing vs. how often you are reading.

Comment: Choosing good indexes is a complete study topic, and totally situational, its not something that can be answered in a simple question here.

Comment: It depends. Is your table a single int column? No, won't be a problem for a single row insert. Is your table 50 nvachar(max) columns? Probably want to test it...

Comment: Bold of you to assume tables have a beginning or end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This all comes down to trade-offs -

If you need to quickly find the values more so than quickly inserting, then keep the index.

If Inserting quickly is more important, maybe consider not indexing.

I'd say from my experience, indexing will always be better - looking up the data quickly is usually the most important, and generally won't slow an `Insert` function by much. This only comes down to if you have [multiple indexes](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/dml/insert#:%7E:text=The%20number%20of%20indexes%20on,the%20slower%20the%20execution%20becomes.) - if just one or two, probably won't have much of an impact.

Comment: And if you're NOT looking up the data, that implies it's safe to, say, insert into a holding table with few indexes, and then batch them at less frequent intervals into the main table (which maybe now is named something like like "myTable_Archive").